# EF Core Distinct + OrderBy Throws Translation Error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have been dealing with a really frustrating EF Core (newest version) error.  I'm not sure at this point if I am doing something wrong or if it's a bug.  Any help the community can provide would be appreciated.

The error is in regards to Entity Framework Core and translating a LINQ expression to SQL.  The below code translates to SQL properly.  The query variable below could potentially have a variety of Where expressions and Includes applied to it with no issue.

```cs
// This works fine
query.Select(price => new Customer {
   Name = price.Payer.Name,
   Code = price.Payer.Code,
   City = price.Payer.City,
   ParentCode = price.Payer.ParentCode,
   ParentLevel = CustomerLevel.Corporate,
   CustomerLevel = CustomerLevel.Payer
}).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

As soon as I add a call to `OrderBy`, it will not evaluate.  If I remove the call to `Distinct`, it once again works, but I can't have both.  I've tried several different ways to build the expression and several workarounds that I've found around the interwebz, and nothing seems to resolve it.

```cs
// This throws error
// query is of type IQueryable<Price>
query.Select(price => new Customer {
   Name = price.Payer.Name,
   Code = price.Payer.Code,
   City = price.Payer.City,
   ParentCode = price.Payer.ParentCode,
   ParentLevel = CustomerLevel.Corporate,
   CustomerLevel = CustomerLevel.Payer
}).Distinct().OrderBy(cust => cust.Name).ToListAsync();
```

Also, placement of the `OrderBy` does not seem to matter.  Based on what I've read, the call to `Distinct` removes all prior ordering, so this one is not too surprising.

```cs
// This also throws error
// query is of type IQueryable<Price>
query
   .OrderBy(price => price.payer.Name)
   .Select(price => new Customer {
      Name = price.Payer.Name,
      Code = price.Payer.Code,
      City = price.Payer.City,
      ParentCode = price.Payer.ParentCode,
      ParentLevel = CustomerLevel.Corporate,
      CustomerLevel = CustomerLevel.Payer
   }).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: EF core 3 is very limited in SQL generation. You have to help it by adding `AsEnumerable` before `OrderBy`, as the exception probably suggests. Please always show exact exception type + message when posting.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the cause of the issue today.   The ParentCode property (used at line `ParentCode = price.Payer.ParentCode`) is actually a property on the base class that is not mapped to the table, so EF apparently did not know what to do with it.  The very strange part of this is that it worked without the `OrderBy`.  Changing that line to `ParentCode = price.Payer.CorporateCode` resolved the issue.

Thanks for anyone that took a look at this.